# TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined(8:38)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I've Solved A Problem That Says `ReferenceError: member is not defined` But Now I'm Getting The Following Problem `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined` I Think That They've Changed The `find` Property To Another Property But I'm Not Sure What's The New Property So... Someone HELP !

**My Code :**

```
1: const discord = require("discord.js");
2: const config = require('../config.json');
3:
4: module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
5:
6:     let target = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first());
7:     let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
8:     let logs = message.guild.channel.find(channel => channel.name === "⚠server_logs");
9:
10:    // member.guild.channels.cache.find('⚠server_logs', config.logsChannel);
11:
12:    if (!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('you don\'t have permissions to use this command!s');
13:
14:    if (!target) return message.reply('please specify a member to ban!');
15:    if (!reason) return message.reply('please specify a reason for this ban!');
16:    if (!logs) return message.reply(`please create a channel called ${config.logsChannel} to log the bans!`);
17:
18:    let embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
19:         .setColor('RANDOM')
20:         .setThumbnail(target.user.avatarURL)
21:         .addField('Banned Member', `${target.user.username} with an ID: ${target.user,id}`)
22:         .addField('Banned By', `${message.author.username} with an ID: ${message.author.id}`)
23:         .addField('Banned Time', message.createdAt)
24:         .addField('Banned At', message.channel)
25:         .addField('Banned Reason', reason)
26:         .addFooter('Banned user information', target.user.displayAvatarURL);
27:
28:    message.channel.send(`${target.user.username} was banned by ${message.author} for ${reason}`);
29:    target.ban(reason);
30:    logs.send(embed);
31: };
32: 
33: module.exports.help = {
34:     name: 'ban'
35: };
```

Comment: `message.guild.channel` is undefined, does not exist, maybe the key is different or is not always there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let logs = message.guild.channel.find

It has to be: "let logs = message.guild.channels.cache.find" , like in your comment i think